# MySql Inner join on a non repeating range of values

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables, where `temp` is updated every minute with real time temperature values, while `ref` is updated once in awhile when the maximum allowed temperature changes.

```
table: temp          table: ref
datetime  temp       datetime  maxtemp
10:10:45  33         10:10:40   55
10:11:44  38         10:14:50   60
10:12:43  37
10:13:45  35        
10:14:44  38        
10:15:43  39
```

I want some kind of join where it is smart enough to use the entry from `ref` table that has a `datetime` smaller than its own, allowing me to view the by minute temperature and what was the max temperature for that minute.
the result should be:

```
table: result         
datetime  temp   datetime  maxtemp
10:10:45  33     10:10:40   55
10:11:44  38     10:10:40   55
10:12:43  37     10:10:40   55
10:13:45  35     10:10:40   55 
10:14:44  38     10:14:50   60  
10:15:43  39     10:14:50   60
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I have anough data to test. 
But here is my approach:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/59c90/8

```
SELECT  t.*, r1.*
from temp t
LEFT JOIN ref r1
ON t.datetime>=r1.datetime
LEFT JOIN ref r
ON r.datetime>r1.datetime
  AND t.datetime>=r.datetime
WHERE r.datetime IS NULL
order BY t.datetime
```

Comment: this does not work on my db,The connection times out because it is very slow (>600 sec)my actual temp is 75000x76 record in size (5.5 mb), the ref is 9300x283 records (2.5 mb),

Comment: do you have index on `datetime` for both tables?  do you have othe columns like `date` or something to make anothre filter?

Comment: datetime(timestamp) is the primary key in both tables